# Kotlin - how to use BodyToMono with Generics and Nested Classes | WebFlux

Tags: spring, kotlin, jackson, spring-webflux

I cannot make it work to map a WebClient response to a data class with generics and/or with nested data classes in Kotlin. What I use is Spring 5 with WebFlux and a Reactive MongoDB

Here is my code for the response of the WebClient and to `.map()` the response to a data class.

```
        var response = CreateBittrexUrl("/account/getbalances", "GET")
            .getWebClient()
            .map { it to Test.Result::class.java } <-- does not work
            .flatMap { it.bodyToMono(Test.Result::class.java) } <-- does not work
            .flatMap { it.toEntity(Wrapper<Account>().retrieveSomething()::class.java) } <-- does also not work with generics
```

Here are my data classes that is nested. I need to get the variable result.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class Test(
    @JsonProperty("success") val success: Boolean = false,
    @JsonProperty("message") val message: String = "",
    @JsonProperty("result") val result: List<Result> = emptyList()
) {

data class Result(
    @JsonProperty("Currency") val currency: String?,
    @JsonProperty("Balance") val balance: Double,
    @JsonProperty("Available") val available: Double,
    @JsonProperty("Pending") val pending: Double,
    @JsonProperty("CryptoAddress") val cryptoAddress: String?,
    @JsonProperty("Requested") val requested: Boolean,
    @JsonProperty("Uuid") val uuid: Any?
)
```

The generic version; note that I use an inline function to get the `class.java` data from the Generic I insert. This is needed for the `BodyToMono()` method

```
data class Wrapper<T: Any>(var succes: Boolean? = false,
                                  var message: String? = "",
                                  var result: T? = null) {

    inline fun <reified T: Any> retrieveSomething() = T::class.java
}
```

And here is the error message that I get when executing a request:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2018-06-03T21:03:52.876+0000",
  "path": "/account/getbalances",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "JSON encoding error: object is not an instance of declaring class; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: object is not an instance of declaring class (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->kotlin.Unit[\"success\"])"
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Added the error msg

Comment: What's the implementation inside map?

Comment: @uneq95 can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Did you solved this problem?